# Unable to use HTTPS for MobileFirst Console 6.3

Tags: https, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am using MobileFirst 6.3 ontop of WAS Liberty 8.5.5.4.
I am able to access the console via HTTP, but fail to do so via HTTPS.

With HTTP:
[image: with http protocol]

With HTTPS:
[image: with https protocol]

This is the server.xml: [server.xml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vihm14kmki5lw20/server.xml?dl=0)
And the messages.log: [messages.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i7nwxelku1d2ttw/messages.log?dl=0)

Comment: The messages.log seems incomplete. Is that all of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must install from IBM fix central the last 6.3 ifix that includes :

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI30521

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI31900

Comment: It's worked fine with "the JNDI property
ibm.worklight.admin.ui.cors.strictssl=false for the Worklight
console application." provided by http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI30521

Thanks a lot