# IBM MobileFirst Operations Console does not work with HTTPS

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are unable to use MobileFirst 6.3 Operations Console with HTTPS. I reviewed a couple of links here and installed the last fix pack available for the server side (6.3.0.0-MFPF-Server-IF201504041503.zip).
We are having the same behavior explained in this link:
[Unable to use HTTPS for MobileFirst Console 6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243429/unable-to-use-https-for-mobilefirst-console-6-3)
Need I install another fix or redeploy worklightconsole.war ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: One additional comment, after the fix install I have my AppCenter console working fine with HTTPS.

Comment: In a production system? development environment? add your messages.log

Comment: We are having the same issue in all the environments that we have (dev, testing and production), all with the same maintenance level).
[messages.log] https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxshAtqKCa9maUxoMFVZOU1hSVE/view?usp=sharing
[console.log] https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxshAtqKCa9mazRlX2QwdlpCaEE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The logs do not provide any error and also appear cut, so it is not clear yet what is the root cause. Can you provide a messages.log that is not cut at the end?

Comment: Hi Idan, 
There is no errors in the logs file. I´m attaching a new set after a server restart, please let me know if I need increase the log details or maybe créate a trace file.
[logs] https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxshAtqKCa9mZ2xxSGplSGhsbEE/view?usp=sharing
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, can't figure out what is the error from the logs.

Comment: Could you turn on two logging parameters and we can see if they might provide any insight? In the server.xml include:
<logging traceSpecification="SSLChannel=all=enabled"/>
and in the jvm.options include:
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl

Comment: Hi Chevy, thanks for your update.
Here you have the logs and trace based on your config: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxshAtqKCa9mSjdwajR2YkpTb2c/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not installed the last MFP 6.3 ifix as you can see in the messages.log file of your last zipped logs :

[4/15/15 12:00:34:754 ART] 00000012 ht.admin.listeners.WorklightManagementServletContextListener I FWLSE3199I: ========= MobileFirst Administration Services version 6.3.0.00-20141127-1357 started.

When you install a fix you have to do a minimal update of the console applications and the runtime applications with the Server config tools or the installation ant tasks. Otherwise no war files are updated.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for your update, agreed that I need upgrade my MobileFirst Administration Services version, but I do not know why.  I installed only the 6.3.0.0-MFPF-Server-IF201504041503 one at server side, without errors reported. Also it changed the appcenter war (6.3.0.00-20150404-1503).  I tried with a fix reinstall (using Installation Manager), having the same status. Need I install another file from the fix pack? Is there an alternative for this war file upgrade?  Thanks

Comment: In fact the Application Center installation is different. The upgrade is automatically done by Installation Manager. When you install MFP with IM it copies only the different files inside the installation directory and does nothing else so it doesn't update the databases and the applications. To update the databases (not needed here) and the applications you need to use the Server config tool or the ant tasks like you did for the installation but with different parameters.

Comment: See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr_upgrading_wl_runtime_install_wladmin.html and http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr_upgrading_wl_runtime_upgrade_runtime_env.html

Comment: Thanks Bruno for your response, the issue was fixes after following your steps.